# Cannot import project into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, import

I wish to import the project found on this site for purposes of Android consumption of RESTful service, but Eclipse notes "project cannot be found":

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/calling-restful-services-from-your-android-app/1076/

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by selecting the option "Existing Android code into Workspace". It seems it doesn't come with the eclipse files but the ones of the android build system.